# Opening a playlist from a different country?

Tags: itunes, playlist, apple-music

I'm trying to open a playlist I saw on twitter (https://itunes.apple.com/us/playlist/made-of-cocaine/idpl.27f9313c33104fb2a5dec76e3694ea63), when I follow the link, iTunes opens on the "New" tab, and that's it. I noticed that the country code is explicitly coded into the url (us), and I'm in a different country (Hong Kong), but I'm having a hard time believing that it would just silently fail because of that. Anyone know what the deal is?

Comment: I'm in France with a French iTunes Store account and I can open the playlist on my iPhone. Your issue has to do with something else.

Comment: Did you fix it yet? I'm home now and can confirm it also works on iTunes with the same French account

Comment: Yes, restarting iTunes fixed it. 8-/ Thanks @Lax!